# How to MakeScreenshot fullpage on Delphi

Tags: android, delphi, listbox, firemonkey

How to "MakeScreenshoot" FullPage on TListBox or VertScrollbox?
I code like this, but the result not full. Some component not captured when i uses "Makescreenshoot".

vsReceipt is a TVertScrollBox, inside which there is lbReceipt (TListBox). I changed to using an anchor because sometimes the default component I use uses Align > Client. Then I adjusted the Height vsReceipt against lbReceipt using lbReceipt.ContentBounds.Size.cy + 24; When I use the "MakeScreenshoot" function, some parts are not captured.

```
    var ABitmap : TBitmap;
    var OldHeight := vsReceipt.Height;
    var AAlign := vsReceipt.Align;
    var AAnchor := vsReceipt.Anchors;
    try
      vsReceipt.Align := TAlignLayout.None;
      vsReceipt.Anchors := [TAnchorKind.akLeft, TAnchorKind.akTop, TAnchorKind.akRight];
      vsReceipt.Height := lbReceipt.ContentBounds.Size.cy + 24;
      ABitmap := lbReceipt.MakeScreenshot;
      if Assigned(ABitmap) then begin
        ABitmap.SaveToFile('bfaprintreceipt.png');
        ABitmap.DisposeOf;
      end;
    finally
      vsReceipt.Align := AAlign;
      vsReceipt.Height := OldHeight;
      vsReceipt.Anchors := AAnchor;
    end;
```

And the result like this

> [image: Result]

I want result like this

> [image]

Comment: There does not appear to be enough information here to figure out the problem.  You should provide a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).  But here are a couple of comments.  1: Is every control ultimately parented to `vsReceipt`?  The screenshot won't include controls sitting above `vsReceipt` but not parented to it. 2: Changing the anchors won't change the size of `vsReceipt`.  Anchors mean that the size of `vsReceipt` will change in line with its parent control, but your code does not show you changing that.